# Android Firebase TIMESTAMP

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Button with onClickListener to post the TIMESTAMP in child("Date")

```
users.child(user.getUid()).child("Date").setValue(ServerValue.TIMESTAMP);
```

It works fine.

**My problem is when I try to retrieve in my APP on the phone, I'm getting the current time not the actual TIMESTAMP time .**

```
 users.child(user.getUid()).child("Date").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                Date date=new Date();
                SimpleDateFormat sfd = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss", Locale.getDefault());
                sfd.format(new Date());



                TimeSold.setText(String.valueOf(date));


            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            }
        });
```

The TIMESTAMP is changing on Firebase and it should be different from user to other. On my App it just gives me the same current time for all users.

My Firebase

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the timestamp is saved as a `Long` value, put:

```
Date date = new Date(dataSnapshot.getValue(Long.class));
SimpleDateFormat sfd = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss", 
                                    Locale.getDefault());
String text = sfd.format(date);
TimeSold.setText(text);
```

in the `onDataChange` callback

Your solution is not working because you're passing the current date to the format, as you wrote down:

```
Date date = new Date()
```

By default it takes the local current time.

Comment: Thank you Marco , i tried your code but i have many underlines red  in it..i think something is missing :(

Answer (score 3):

> my problem is when i try to retrieve in my APP on the phone,i'm getting the current time not the actual TIMESTAMP time .

This is happening because inside the callback you are actually creating a new `Date` object rather then getting it from the database. To solve this, please use the following method:

```
public static String getTimeDate(long timestamp){
    try{
        DateFormat dateFormat = getDateTimeInstance();
        Date netDate = (new Date(timestamp));
        return dateFormat.format(netDate);
    } catch(Exception e) {
        return "date";
    }
}
```

And the following lines of code to get the date from the database:

```
ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        long date = ds.getValue(Long.class);
        Log.d(TAG, getTimeDate(date));
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
        Log.d(TAG, databaseError.getMessage()); //Don't ignore errors!
    }
};
users.child(user.getUid()).child("Date").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener);
```

**Edit:**

To use your formated Date, please use the following method:

```
public static String getTimeDate(long timestamp){
    try{
        Date netDate = (new Date(timestamp));
        SimpleDateFormat sfd = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss", Locale.getDefault());
        return sfd.format(netDate);
    } catch(Exception e) {
        return "date";
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Alex , i can now get the actual TIMESTAMP but i want it written with normal format "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss". What should i change in my code ???

Comment: Good to hear that it worked! :) To use your formated Date, please see my updated answer.

Comment: Thank you Alex ,appreciate your effort :) now its working 
both answers are accepted but i checked Marco's answer first.

Comment: You're welcome but you need to know that this is not how things work in this comunity. It's true that Marco answered 18 second earlier but he [edited](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/54329650/revisions) his answer after 2 hours by adding code from my answer. The the rule is to reward the first one who's answering your question in the correct way. So hope you reconsider accepting the right answer.